# Need to customize the Avairy API in Android?

Tags: android, photos

I am working on Editing Photos with Frames and Stickers. I have the code of **Aviary API SDK** which is working superbly.

Now my requirements are like, I want to add my own FRAMES and STICKERS in my application so that I can use them in place of AVIARY SDK downloaded images. Is it possible to do this with some other code.

Please suggest me. My requirements is just **FRAME and STICKERS on photos**.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like as of now, these kind of customizations are available only for licensed uses, which is very expensive.

http://www.aviary.com/licensing

**Enterprise** options says:

> Provide your own assets for effects, stickers and frames

but the price is per-contract, so it won't be cheaper than 1500 USD/month in my opinion.